# how to make a radial array on a sphere in blender

Tags: modifiers, snapping

I know how to create a radial array on a flat surface. i need someone with skills and imagination to understand I want the array to sit on a sphere and conform to the curve of the sphere(wrap).

Comment: Maybe use instances on a UV sphere instead of Array modifier?

Comment: A complete squashed  wrap, or just the touching surface?

Comment: Related: [Change number of segments for each ring on UV sphere (Geometry Nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/292084/60486), also [Modelling a spiral around a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42131/60486)

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is through instancing on a sphere, where you parent the array object to the sphere:

[image]

Either with faces, or with Vertices (aligned to vertex normal)

[image]

[image]